# Problem with loading static files on Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I'm using Django 3.0.3 and Python 3.7.6.

I followed Django documentation on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/ but I can't find out what's wrong.

Directory:

```
project_name
   -app_name
   -static
      -css
         -main.css
      -js
      ...
   -project_name
      ...
      -settings.py
```

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
...
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

When I try to use static files in my templates:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/main.css" %}">
```

pycharm shows
`unresolved template reference '"css/main.css"'`

terminal shows
`"GET /static/css/animate.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1671`

Comment: Can you reformat your directory listing so it makes sense?

Comment: Have you: 1) defined STATIC_ROOT and/or STATICFILES_DIRS 2) run collectstatic 3) added urlpatterns for static files? DEBUG=true or false?

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I've just started to learn Django, and these tips have helped me to understand it better.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem after these steps:

1.Add the following code in settings.py

`STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'),
)`

2.Add `type="text/css"` in my template

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/main.css" %}">`

Although it works for me, I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your url.py

```
    urlpatterns+=static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns+=static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

I met same your problem, but i'm using `django 3.1`.
I only add this line as [official document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/):

In settings.py

```
...
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'static']
```

In file .html

```
{% load static %}
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/application.css' %}" type="text/css" />
```

And it worked as well.